# R Coarsened Exact Matching, list with matched controls

Tags: object, matching, exact-match, matchit

I was wondering if it was possible to extract a list when creating a cem object that includes the matched control individuals or samples. I use the cem function to do coarsened exact matching but I would like to get an overview of which controls have been chosen. Any idea on how to go about this?

Comment: Are you using the `cem` package or `MatchIt`? In `MatchIt`, yo can just use `match.data()`, the same as with all matching methods. Otherwise, you can just subset your data to those with weights greater than 0. Remember that you must include the weights when estimating the treatment effect unless you set `k2k = TRUE` (in either package).